# MSAL and React-Admin integration

Tags: react-admin, azure-ad-msal

How do I integrate MSAL with React-Admin properly.

I used the code provided by Microsoft and put it in the Constructor in App.js and it works fine using a redirect method, except that I keep getting a default React-Admin login screen for split second before it redirects to MS authentication page.

If I put the MSAL code in my custom login page (empty page), it goes into a loop and authentication does not work.

How do I get rid of the React-Admin login screen?

```
import { UserAgentApplication } from 'msal';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.userAgentApplication = new UserAgentApplication({
        auth: {
          clientId: config.appId,
          authority: config.authEndPoint,
        },
        cache: {
          cacheLocation: "localStorage",
          storeAuthStateInCookie: true
        }
      });

      this.userAgentApplication.handleRedirectCallback(this.authCallback.bind(this));

      var user = this.userAgentApplication.getAccount();
      if (user != null) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', user.idToken);
        localStorage.setItem('userName', user.userName);
        const userName = user.userName.toString();

        fetch('http://localhost:5000/getuserid', {
          mode: 'cors',
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'USERNAME': userName
          },
        }).then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
            if (res.id != null) {
                localStorage.setItem('userID', res.id);
            } else {
              console.log('Failed to retreived id');
            }
          }).catch(
            err => console.log(err))
      }

      this.state = {
        isAuthenticated: (user !== null),
        user: {},
        error: null
      };

      if (user) {
        // Enhance user object with data from Graph
        //this.getUserProfile();
      }
      else {
        const loginRequest = {
          scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"]
        }

        this.userAgentApplication.loginRedirect(loginRequest);
      }
    }

    authCallback(error, response) {
      //handle redirect response
      this.setState({
        authenticated: true
      });
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <Admin title="MyApp" >
    ...
      </Admin>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Could you update your post with code examples?

Comment: I have updated the post to include the MSAL code I use in my App.js.
The app needs to be registered with Azure AD though, in order to work, an dthe configuration is in separate confg.js fiel

Answer (score 2):

I worked a bit on your example and I have a solution.
I have read mostly React-Admin Tutorial https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html
but also a custom React AAD MSAL library docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aad-msal#react-aad-msal

Please add such a package to your project via docs example.

My code for App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Admin, ListGuesser, Resource} from 'react-admin';
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';
import { AzureAD } from 'react-aad-msal';

// import App from './App';
import { authProvider } from './authProvider';

const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com');

const AdminApp = () => (
  <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
    <Resource name="users" list={ListGuesser}/>
  </Admin>
);

const App = () => (
  <AzureAD provider={authProvider} forceLogin={true}>
    <AdminApp />
  </AzureAD>
);

export default App;
```

And for authProvider.js

```
// authProvider.js
import { MsalAuthProvider, LoginType } from 'react-aad-msal';

// Msal Configurations
const config = {
  auth: {
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT_ID/',
    clientId: 'MY_APP_ID',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/'
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true
  }
};

// Authentication Parameters
const authenticationParameters = {
  scopes: [
    'User.Read'
  ]
}

// Options
const options = {
  loginType: LoginType.Redirect,
  tokenRefreshUri: window.location.origin + '/auth.html'
}

export const authProvider = new MsalAuthProvider(config, authenticationParameters, options)
```

That solution displays react-admin only when MS Authentication is successful.
It's not using the default Login page at all.

Next step probably here will be merging that solution with using react-admin logout button based on the following docs:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/2.8/Authentication.html#customizing-the-login-and-logout-components
and how to call the following MSAL logout function: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-aad-msal#azuread-component